# Raspberry Pi Pico interfacing Rpi4B / WinPC Thonny Python IDE Problem

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop, pi-pico

I am new to Raspberry in general so I dont have a lot of experience with these devices.

I recently bought the raspberry pi pico and downloaded the micropython file from raspberry´s website. Everyting was going great but when I turned my raspberry off, the next day the Pico was not being recognized by the Thonny IDE (in the previous day Thonny was recognizing and working great.)

I tried connecting to the PC and download again the files. And it worked! But when I tried to connect to the raspberry again there was no sign off life.

I tried connecting again and again but there is no sign of life. I even tried pressing the Bootsell button while connecting but nothing happened.

If u can help me I would be very gratefull. And if you need more info just ask and I will tell u what happened in more detail.

Thanks for the attention, André

Comment: When you connect the pico to raspberry pi, can you see any messages in the output of `dmesg` that may relate to the pico

Comment: @ANDRE_21, Let me clarify your situation. (1) You are using a PC (assuming Win7/10, please let me know otherwise) to "download" and  "copy" the "file" to Pico.  (2) You installed python 3.9 and Thonny 3.3.3 on your WinPC. (3) You use an USB cable to connect PC to Pico. (4) You start Thonny 3.3.3 at your PC. (4) You are not connecting any Rpi1/2/3/4 (assuming you have any of them) to Pico. My experience: I did (1) to (4) above and did not have any of your problems.

Comment: (5) I started everything from PCWin10 and use Win10 python 3.9 and Thonny 3.3.3 to play with Pico and everything goes smoothly. I later disconnect USB cable from PC and connect it to Rpi4B, and Rpi4B Thonny runs Pico also smoothly, without any extra installation. (6) I remember I once had another trouble because the buster is not up to date or corrupted, and I can only use python 3.7.3 and thonny 3.3.0 which had teeth problems. Later I used a fresh copy of buster and everything works again.

Comment: (7) I would suggest the following: (8) put away Rpi4B and only use WinPC and Pico. (9) Let me know if you still have trouble. (reply to @tlfong01). Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: (10) If you start everything all over with PCWin10 (me Chinese Win 10) and Pico and got things running smoothly using Thonny, I would suggest NOT to touch Rpi4B for now (I did touch with Rpi4B and found everyting OK, but I stopped there), because I think PC/Rpi buster/Linux ubuntu/ESP 3.9/3.7.3 Thonny 3.3.0/3.3.3 if using Pico Intrepreter mode should run "almost"t the same.

Comment: In other words, if WinPC (My 6 years old WinPC still runs "much" faster than Rpi4B) is handy, there is no point using Rpi4B now, in our learning stage, because we can always "downgrade" to slower Rpi4B (not to mention Rpi2/3) later.  I would recommend to read the very useful answer by @Kelby Criswell．　

Problem copying Micropython from Rpi2 to Pico - RpiSE, Kelby Criswell 2021feb24
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/problem-copying-micropython-from-rpi2-to-pico

Comment: Please confirm if you have a ***PC Win10*** to try again. Perhaps me or other readers can try to repeat your installation steps.

Comment: I may have misunderstood - is there a raspberry pi involved at all? "raspberry" could be anything - best to be specific about what you're talking about

Comment: @Jaromanda, yes, it is very confusing. That is why I keep using "Rp4B" and "Pico" to avoid confusion and ambiguity. You might like to read #Kelby Criswell answer to the other question I referred that he has tried to install microPython to Pico using three separate "development" machines, WinPC, LinuxPC, and Rpi2.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that detail  I connected the Pico to my PC ( windows 10) and to my raspberry Pi 4

Comment: Later today I am going to try follow your suggestions. Thanks a lot for the attention. I’ll make sure to update u when my lessons today end.

Comment: Hey again, I followed your advices and I believe it started working again. I used my PC and changed some cables and now it is alive . Anyway, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Ah, I am glad that you have solved your Thonny setup problem. Now you can explore more advanced stuff. :)  Happy learning. Cheers.